# Remove everything in a third column but only keep specific text

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a data set with three columns:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gtCssfAXHxRjGfX8uTAaimGPWCA2cnci/view?usp=sharing

Here are the first few lines:

```
ID  transcript_id   go_description
MA_10000213g0010    MA_10000213g0010    
MA_10000405g0010    MA_10000405g0010    GO:0006468-protein phosphorylation;GO:0030246-carbohydrate binding;GO:0005524-ATP binding;GO:0004672-protein kinase activity
MA_1000049g0010 MA_1000049g0010 
MA_10000516g0010    MA_10000516g0010    GO:0005515-protein binding
MA_10001015g0010    MA_10001015g0010    
MA_10001337g0010    MA_10001337g0010    
MA_10001425g0010    MA_10001425g0010    
MA_10001478g0010    MA_10001478g0010    
MA_10001558g0010    MA_10001558g0010    
MA_10001g0010   MA_10001g0010   
MA_10002030g0010    MA_10002030g0010    GO:0005737-cytoplasm;GO:0000184-nuclear-transcribed mRNA catabolic process, nonsense-mediated decay;GO:0004386-helicase activity;GO:0008270-zinc ion binding;GO:0003677-DNA binding;GO:0005524-ATP binding
MA_10002157g0010    MA_10002157g0010    GO:0006468-protein phosphorylation;GO:0005524-ATP binding;GO:0004672-protein kinase activity
MA_10002549g0010    MA_10002549g0010    
MA_10002583g0010    MA_10002583g0010    GO:0008168-methyltransferase activity
MA_10002614g0010    MA_10002614g0010    
MA_10002643g0010    MA_10002643g0010    GO:0055114-oxidation-reduction process
```

In the third column, I would like to remove all the text and only keep the `GO:xxxxxxx` where each of these terms should be separated by a comma. For example:

```
GO:0006468, GO:0030246
```

The first two columns should remain unchanged. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the field separator? Can we assume tabs?

Comment: They are four spaces as it seems.

Comment: Then please download it as tab separated since you cannot use space as a separator when your fields also contain spaces (e.g. `GO:0030246-carbohydrate binding;`). You can do that directly from Google Sheets: File=> Download => Tab Separated Values (tsv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*AWK*:

```
$ awk '
     BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     {
  while(match($3,/GO:[0-9]+/)) 
     {
  col= sprintf("%s",((col) ? col ",": "")substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH));  
  $3= substr($3,RSTART+RLENGTH)
     }
     }
  col{ $3=col; col=""}
  1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data are tab separated, you can do this:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '
  $F[2] = join(",", $F[2]=~/GO:\d+/g); 
  print join "\t",@F
' gene_table_Go\ -\ gene_table_Go.tsv > fixed.tsv
```

The `-a` makes `perl` act like `awk` nd split each input line into the array `@F` on the character given by `-F`. Here, I am passing a tab (you can always save your file as tab separated if it isn't already). Next, I am setting the third field, `$F[2]`, to be the result of joining all occurrences of `GO:` followed by digits present in the existing 3rd field, in other words, keeping only the GO terms and nothing else. Then, I print the `@F` array joined by tabs.

Here's a more condensed version of the same basic idea:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '
 $,="\t"; 
 print @F[0..1], join(",",$F[2]=~/GO:\d+/g);
' gene_table_Go\ -\ gene_table_Go.tsv
```

Both examples produce the same output:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane '$,="\t"; print @F[0,1], join(",",$F[2]=~/GO:\d+/g);' gene_table_Go\ -\ gene_table_Go.tsv | head
ID  transcript_id   
MA_10000213g0010    MA_10000213g0010    
MA_10000405g0010    MA_10000405g0010    GO:0006468,GO:0030246,GO:0005524,GO:0004672
MA_1000049g0010 MA_1000049g0010 
MA_10000516g0010    MA_10000516g0010    GO:0005515
MA_10001015g0010    MA_10001015g0010    
MA_10001337g0010    MA_10001337g0010    
MA_10001425g0010    MA_10001425g0010    
MA_10001478g0010    MA_10001478g0010    
MA_10001558g0010    MA_10001558g0010
```

To also keep the header intact, since it doesn't actually match the `GO:\d+` pattern, you can do:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane '$,="\t"; print $. == 1 ? @F : @F[0,1], join(",",$F[2]=~/GO:\d+/g);' gene_table_Go\ -\ gene_table_Go.tsv | head
ID  transcript_id   go_description
MA_10000213g0010    MA_10000213g0010    
MA_10000405g0010    MA_10000405g0010    GO:0006468,GO:0030246,GO:0005524,GO:0004672
MA_1000049g0010 MA_1000049g0010 
MA_10000516g0010    MA_10000516g0010    GO:0005515
MA_10001015g0010    MA_10001015g0010    
MA_10001337g0010    MA_10001337g0010    
MA_10001425g0010    MA_10001425g0010    
MA_10001478g0010    MA_10001478g0010    
MA_10001558g0010    MA_10001558g0010
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Assuming `\t` tab as column separator:*

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN put get;   \
             my @a = .split(:skip-empty, / \t /, 3);   \
             @a[2] = (@a[2] // "").comb(/ GO\: \d+ /).join(",");   \
             @a.join("\t").trim-trailing.put;'   file
```

Here's an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Going line by line:

1. The `BEGIN` statement out`put`s the header line (can be omitted if the header line is `\t` tab separated like the body rows).
2. The body lines (rows) can be split on `\t` and saved into `@a` array. Note, it might be possible (but risky) to split on `\s**4` i.e. four-consecutive whitespace characters, or even `\h**4` (four-consecutive *horizontal* whitespace characters), if the third column does not contain that pattern. But again, this is risky.
3. The third column (i.e. `@a[2]`) is replaced by `@a[2]` column text that has been `comb`ed (i.e. positively-selected) for one-or-more matches to the Regex `GO\: \d+`. Think of `comb` as the converse of `split` (which is destructive). The selected `GO`-IDs are then joined with commas.
4. Finally, the `split` columns are `join`ed back together on `\t` tabs, and out`put`.

Sample Input:

```
ID  transcript_id   go_description
MA_10000213g0010    MA_10000213g0010
MA_10000405g0010    MA_10000405g0010    GO:0006468-protein phosphorylation;GO:0030246-carbohydrate binding;GO:0005524-ATP binding;GO:0004672-protein kinase activity
MA_1000049g0010 MA_1000049g0010
MA_10000516g0010    MA_10000516g0010    GO:0005515-protein binding
MA_10001015g0010    MA_10001015g0010
MA_10001337g0010    MA_10001337g0010
MA_10001425g0010    MA_10001425g0010
MA_10001478g0010    MA_10001478g0010
MA_10001558g0010    MA_10001558g0010
MA_10001g0010   MA_10001g0010
MA_10002030g0010    MA_10002030g0010    GO:0005737-cytoplasm;GO:0000184-nuclear-transcribed mRNA catabolic process, nonsense-mediated decay;GO:0004386-helicase activity;GO:0008270-zinc ion binding;GO:0003677-DNA binding;GO:0005524-ATP binding
MA_10002157g0010    MA_10002157g0010    GO:0006468-protein phosphorylation;GO:0005524-ATP binding;GO:0004672-protein kinase activity
MA_10002549g0010    MA_10002549g0010
MA_10002583g0010    MA_10002583g0010    GO:0008168-methyltransferase activity
MA_10002614g0010    MA_10002614g0010
MA_10002643g0010    MA_10002643g0010    GO:0055114-oxidation-reduction process
```

Sample Output:

```
ID  transcript_id   go_description
MA_10000213g0010    MA_10000213g0010
MA_10000405g0010    MA_10000405g0010    GO:0006468,GO:0030246,GO:0005524,GO:0004672
MA_1000049g0010 MA_1000049g0010
MA_10000516g0010    MA_10000516g0010    GO:0005515
MA_10001015g0010    MA_10001015g0010
MA_10001337g0010    MA_10001337g0010
MA_10001425g0010    MA_10001425g0010
MA_10001478g0010    MA_10001478g0010
MA_10001558g0010    MA_10001558g0010
MA_10001g0010   MA_10001g0010
MA_10002030g0010    MA_10002030g0010    GO:0005737,GO:0000184,GO:0004386,GO:0008270,GO:0003677,GO:0005524
MA_10002157g0010    MA_10002157g0010    GO:0006468,GO:0005524,GO:0004672
MA_10002549g0010    MA_10002549g0010
MA_10002583g0010    MA_10002583g0010    GO:0008168
MA_10002614g0010    MA_10002614g0010
MA_10002643g0010    MA_10002643g0010    GO:0055114
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/), which has built in support for TSV files - for example

- split the `$go_description` field on `;` into an array
- apply a regular expression to extract the `GO:nnnnnn` substring from each element of the array
- join the result back into a `,` separated string
- assign the result back to `$go_description`

So

```
mlr --tsv put '
  $go_description = joinv(
    apply(splitax($go_description,";"),func(e) {return regextract(e,"GO:[[:digit:]]+")}),
    ","
  )
' gene_table_Go.tsv
```